# Slice the name of a data frame to extract the year

Tags: python, pandas

I wan to automatically get the name of each data frame -as a string- and slice that string to get the last 4 characters, which is the year. In every solution I found that the name of the data frame needs to be kinda re-assigned again, which doesn't work for me in this case.

So far I've tried:

```
for df in (grid_2010, grid_2018, grid_2022):
    df_year = str(df)
    print('{}: col1 vs. col2'.format(df_year[-4]))
    print(df['col1'].corr(df['col2']))
```

but I get an 'm' instead of the year...

```
m: col1 vs. col2
0.9915766248731003
m: col1 vs. col2
0.9660661083576073
m: col1 vs. col2
0.9537479266164907
```

and I want:

```
2010: col1 vs. col2
0.9915766248731003
2018: col1 vs. col2
0.9660661083576073
2022: col1 vs. col2
0.9537479266164907
```

I've also tried sending each df as an item in a list and slice accordingly:

```
for df in (grid_2010, grid_2018, grid_2022):
    df_year = list[str(df)]
    print('{}: col1 vs. col2'.format(df_year[0][-4]))
    print(df['col1'].corr(df['col2']))
```

...but I get the exact same result as above. I'm trying for a way to map the df to its corresponding year in a list, but so far no luck.

This is a subset view of one of the data frames, with the columns I need. All data frames have same structure, just different name (as above) and column values, obviously

```
    Col1  Col2
0  42244  1078
1  56068  1285
2  63894  1860
3   5850   664
```

Any help and/or suggestions welcome!

Comment: Can you show what one of your data frames would look like? It would make helping easier.

Comment: @MarceloPaco Thanks for replying. I couldn't replicate the data frame here in the comments, but it has 11 columns (col1.... col11), all of them numerical ones (as in int64)

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you should add it in your question. Not the comments.

Comment: if your df_year[0] is a string, then here `df_year[0][-4]` - you're taken 4th from the right element of the string ( for example from 12/34/5678 you'll get just 5). But you need to take a slice `[from:to:step]`. So it should be `df_year[0][-4:]`.

Comment: @MarceloPaco Will do. I've just edited the question as I realized I had different variable name which may be confusing

Comment: Does `str(df)` actually contain the year? My understanding was that a Series could have a name, but a DataFrame cannot.

Comment: @ArtemStrogin I tried but it returned an error...
`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-65-e58ca0fb26b2>", line 2, in <module>
    df_year = list[str(df)]

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: why are you converting your string into list?

Comment: Aside from the dataframe variable name being `grid_2010` is the year stored anywhere in the dataframe?

Comment: @NickODell the name of the dataframe is grid_2010 (for example) so by slicing to get the last 4 characters of the name I'd then get the year... but, trying to automatically get the dataframe name as a string is the problem I'm trying to solve  :(

Comment: @MarceloPaco No but... this is a great idea! I could just add a column with the value of the year -which will repeat- and then pass `str(grid_2010.year.unique())` to `.format()` and see what it does. Although it does mean adding more data, it is increasingly dawning on me that getting the dataframe name automatically might not be so straight-forward as I initially thought, in which case it is probably more sensible to add an extra column.

Comment: @Vanessa_C Technically the name of the *variable* is grid_2010. You can get a variable name by calling `locals()` or `globals()`, but it's not recommended.

Comment: If you're defining the year why not do something like this: `for df in ((grid_2010, 2010), (grid_2018, 2018), (grid_2022, 2022)):`? then you can index the data frame like `df[0]` and the year with `df[1]`.

Comment: @MarceloPaco It works!! Thank you!!!!  I passed `((grid_2010, 2010), (grid_2018, 2018), (grid_2022, 2022))` to variable `df_year_tuple` then I looped  `for item in df_year_tuple:` then `df_year = str(item[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, since the year is not in the dataframe and the only way you know the year is because of your variable declaration, you can use `tuples` in your for loop.

```
for df, year in ((grid_2010, 2010), (grid_2018, 2018), (grid_2022, 2022)):
    print('{}: col1 vs. col2'.format(year))
    print(df['col1'].corr(df['col2']))
```